# Resources/papers on Portuguese nominal syntax and determiners?

Tags: syntax, reference-request, articles, portuguese, determiners

I'm vaguely aware that the (definite) determiner has a much freer distribution in Portuguese than in other languages, e.g. it can come before personal names:

> A Maria lê um livro.
>
> The Maria reads a book

And before possessive pronouns:

> O meu amigo é inteligente.
>
> The my friend is intelligent.

And before (some?) wh-words:

> O que você está fazendo?
>
> The what you are doing?

Does anyone know of any papers offering an analysis for the structure of the Portuguese NP/DP in light of these facts? Barring that, can anyone recommend a good source for a comprehensive description of the distribution of Portuguese determiners?

Comment: Perhaps [this paper](http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/people/grads/lima/Lima_ABRALIN_Paper.pdf) and the references in it might help.

Comment: I think Catalan also requires a definite determiner before personal subjects.